# Note-taking app with flashcards (or with Anki export)

Tags: note-taking, microsoft-onenote, flashcard, anki, spaced-repetition

I'm using OneNote to take notes and Anki to remember information. I'm spending a lot of time to transfer OneNote notes to Anki and sometimes it's hard to remember if I've already transferred particular note or not. Also, it's hard to update the existing notes/flashcards.

So I'm looking for a software which can make this process easier.

I've googled a lot and already looked at "Mochi Cards" and "Nimblenotes", but they aren't work right.

Comment: Why not take notes inside Anki directly?

Comment: Because sometimes I need to review my notes, and notes in OneNote have a unified structure, while the order of cards in the in Anki Browser depends on the date of repetition.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what a "unified structure" is. Thanks! :-)

Comment: In the Anki cards browser you can order by date of addition.

Comment: Oh, sorry for my bad level of English. I've meant that OneNote gives me possibility to organize my Notes and it has a great structure with Notebooks, pages and subpages. 
Thank you for your advice, ordering by date makes it easier to find needed card.  Also, I found a "Hierarchical Tags" which also helps a lot.